Yii2 md5 with RSA signature
im trying to connect to a API. the documentation need me to use md5 with rsa encryption. this is my 1st time doing this, and i've gotten this far
use phpseclib3\Crypt\RSA;
use phpseclib3\Crypt\PublicKeyLoader;

        $string = 'fl_testENQJKAZXT00JJA0012202024-04-30 15:30:41.446';

        // Load the private key
        $privateKeyPath = Yii::getAlias('@webroot').'/bla.key'; //1024-bit
        $privateKeyContents = file_get_contents($privateKeyPath);

        // Load the private key into the RSA object
        $privateKey = PublicKeyLoader::load($privateKeyContents);
        
        // Set the signature mode
        $privateKey = $privateKey->withPadding(RSA::SIGNATURE_PKCS1)->withHash('md5'); 

        $signature = $privateKey->sign($string);
        $signature = base64_encode($signature);

        echo $privateKey->getPublicKey()->verify($string, $signature) ?
            'valid signature' :
            'invalid signature';
        die;

When i post to the client using curl, i don't get to connect. when i added this code
echo $privateKey->getPublicKey()->verify($string, $signature) ?
            'valid signature' :
            'invalid signature';
        die;

i get invalid signature
documentation says this
Signature will be signed based on the following string:
fl_testENQJKAZXT00JJA0012202024-04-30 15:30:41.446

Sample of resulting signature value equals to (using MD5withRSA algorithm)

oJDaZ5Xu3m+k8zG\/KzIphNEvOjo8vVYl\/OXMdbE+Aghrj6H9Vq22vdBnqD940XhaPscxPVpq0xMV+huLYPySN
TsPzWrah88OXyCbOyqaY2STE2TAZ9Hk49zAgNV0qj5spQWUto6tHbWbq\/SkwWD5uhkhvKOavBIZ3IFLHV2JI
tM=

is this how to md5 with rsa a string? is my code correct atleast? im not getting any errors on my side and i still can't connect to their API

"md5 with rsa encryption" - what exactly does that mean? What does "i don't get to connect" mean? Are you facing any specific error message?

no error message. i just can't connect to the api. their server not throwing any error message thats helpful either. wondering if my code is wrong?

The code you've shared does not connect to any API

yeah thats just the encryption part, didn't include the curl

If you have a known plaintext and the key to run a sample encryption, why not do that to see whether your code produces the same output?

You should specify the library used. PublicKeyLoader::load() points to phpseclib. I recommend taking a look at the documentation. The hashing is implicit, the digest is set with withHash() (the default is SHA256). Also, OAEP is used by default. Check which padidng the API requires, possibly PKCS#1 v1.5.

MD5withRSA specifies an algorithm for signing (not encrypting!) with RSA using PKCS#1 v1.5 padding and MD5 as digest, see here. For signing, the private key is required (the public key is used for verification).

@Topaco like this? $rsa = PublicKeyLoader::load($privateKeyContents)->withPadding('PKCS#1 v1.5')->withHash('md5');   $encrypted = $rsa->sign($string);

Just follow the documentation, e.g. apply withPadding(RSA::SIGNATURE_PKCS1) (and not withPadding('PKCS#1 v1.5')). Not so important, but $encrypted is actually the wrong term, the result is a signature.

It's also worth noting that MD5 is not considered secure, and in particular is not secure in this application.

@Topaco updated the question with new code. added this echo $privateKey->getPublicKey()->verify($string, $signature) ?             'valid signature' :             'invalid signature';         die; and get invalid signature

@PresidentJamesK.Polk i see, unfortunately out of my control. im just trying to connect to their API

@Topaco got it. removed $signature = base64_encode($signature); and i get valid signature thank you.
